# Trying to create a bar chart from this DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[Dataframe Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6NMx.png)

I want the headers on the top to be on the x-axis and the number of occurrences to be on the y-axis. I tried using this: df.plot(kind='bar') but the output wasn't formatted how I want it.

Comment: Maybe transposing the dataframe? `df.T.plot(kind='bar')`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you!